# Can not post to facebook wall showing "Can not post to wall"

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to post a status to facebook from my android apps...I have done the thing in a demo project and its runnning well when i am trying to do it in my own project ,after installing facebook in the device it is showing "can not post to wall"...
Here is a snap of my logcat

[image]

Any suggestion please....

Comment: What's the error message from Facebook? all you've included there is a  big stacktrace. I do see a lookupHostByName() in there though - are you sure your JVM is setup to access the internet properly?

Comment: you are running `A Network Request` on main UI thread. Android OS >=3.0 does not allow to make Network request on UI thread. Use `Async Task`. May be post some code so that some one can help.

Comment: The message it is showing is "Failed to post to facebook wall"...And the OS version is 4.0.1 i think it may create a mess @M MOhsin

Comment: and the permission i have taken...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: 'Failed to post to facebook wall' is not an error message from the API as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Don't perform network operation on the main UI. You can start a async task and post the message in it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.